# HTTPS share link redirects to HTTP (not HTTPS) full link

Tags: bug, ssl

It would probably make sense to keep the user on HTTP**S** version of StackOverflow when he opens an HTTP**S** short URL like `https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345678`.

Currently, the user is automatically redirected to HTTP *regardless* of whether the protocol of the original short URL is secure HTTP**S** or regular HTTP.

Comment: I just tried to repro this with this post and could not. It redirected correctly to https using Chrome stable on Windows 7

Comment: @TinyGiant: The server indeed sends back a `http` location. Are you using HTTPEverywhere perhaps?

Comment: Reproduced: https://pastebin.com/0iK1vZVw

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not using HTTPSEverywhere, and I did try it in incognito mode.

Comment: Note however, than HTTPS support is *not yet official*. There is only official HTTPS support for meta.stackoverflow.com and meta.stackexchange.com at this point in time.

Comment: That's the issue, I was attempting to reproduce it with _this_ meta post. When attempting to reproduce it with a post from the main site, it does indeed redirect to HTTP. @martijn

Comment: @TinyGiant: yes, that's because HTTPS support for Meta is now switched on.

Comment: Given that this works correctly for meta.stackoverflow.com, I'm duping this to the canonical HTTPS transition post. Once StackOverflow.com *officially* supports HTTPS, this'll be automatically fixed too. Until then: not a bug, because it's not supported.

Comment: Also see the Meta.SE central post: [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058). Stack Overflow is on the list, just not completed yet.